# How to clear cache or make the images run the code again in html?

Tags: php, html, caching

I was running this code

```
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=funil&interval=1"/>
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=funil&interval=3"/>
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=conversao&interval=2"/>
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=conversao&interval=3"/>
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=nps&interval=2"/>
```

That generates an image in a folder that the rest of the code use later, but it only works one time or pressing ctrl +f5 which clears cache if im not wrong...

So i need a way to renew this images everytime i call the php or somehow clear the cache but without using headers... what can i do?

Comment: What do you mean that this code only works one time?  It's just some static HTML, it should work identically every time unless there's something wrong with `g_builder.php`.  If you mean that `g_builder.php` is only called one time, then change your response caching headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could append the timestamp as a property to the end of the src attribute. For example:

```
<img src="../graphics/g_builder.php?type=nps&amp;interval=2&amp;time=<?php print time(); ?>"/>
```

This way, every time you refresh the page, the src attribute will be different.